# bash: different sort output on files with identical first column

Tags: bash, sorting, csv

Sorry for the vague title, I couldn't think of a better one...

I have **2 tab-delimited files** with identical first columns (different numbers of total columns). I would like to sort **both files by their first column.**

I think I could do this either with it -t\t option or the -k1,12 option (since first column is never longer than 12 characters.) Both options produce the same (wrong) output.

Even though both files have the same first column, they are sorted differently. Notice that on the file1 I get **23,29,2;** file2, I get **2,23,29.**

```
$ head  file1 | sort -t\t | cut -f1
rs1000000
rs10000010
rs10000012
rs10000013
rs10000017
rs10000023
rs10000029
rs1000002
rs10000030

$ head file2 | sort -t\t | cut -f1
rs1000000
rs10000010
rs10000012
rs10000013
rs10000017
rs1000002
rs10000023
rs10000029
rs10000030
```

**how I can I sort both files such that the first column is in the same order in each?**
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 1,1
```

Use `$'\t'` to have the shell interpret `\t` as a tab since `sort` doesn't parse escape sequences. Use `-k` to tell it to only sort on the first field rather than the entire line.

You might also want the `-V` flag if you want `2` to sort in between `0` and `10`.